# Deploying Craft on Apache Server - Error code 255

Tags: craft3, deployment

I'm trying to deploy our Craft 3 site on an Apache server. When running `composer install` I get the following error.

> @php nys-setup update
>   Script @php nys-setup update handling the post-install-cmd event returned with error code 255

Does anyone know what the reason could be or where I could get more detail on the error?

Comment: Check your `storage/logs/console.log` for details. I think there is a semver conflict in my scaffoloding

Comment: That error was due to the php version not being specified when I had executed the command. I've tried running it with the specified path to the current php version and it seemed to work.

Comment: @DanLee can you add that as an official answer?

Answer (score 1):

That error was due to the php version not being specified when I had executed the command. I've tried running it with the specified path to the current php version and it seemed to work.